# Java file path issue

Tags: java, csv, tomcat

I work on a Java project with an old Framework EchoStudio3 with a Tomcat Server.
I try to download a generated csv file, but i get a strange file instead.

Here is my code:

```
String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File filename = new File(dir, "reports.csv");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);

fw.append("User");name
fw.append(',');
fw.append("Count");
fw.append('\n');
fw.append("Bob");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("20");
fw.append('\n');
fw.append("John");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("5");
fw.append('\n');
fw.append("Mike");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("2");
fw.append('\n');
fw.append("Total");
fw.append(',');
fw.append("27");
fw.append('\n');

try {
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
    URL url = new URL("file:///" + dir);
    FileURLConnection urlConn = (FileURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    String contentType = "text/csv";
    ApplicationInstance.getActive().enqueueCommand(new DownloadCommand(
              new FileDownload(contentType,"inline", 
              filename.getAbsolutePath(), 
              urlConn.getInputStream())));

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter !!!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I Have a Tomcat server on a local Windows environment where I test my code, but the deployed environment will be a linux environment, I don't know if this will cause another issue, but I think you should now.
The download file from the code above, is named "C-Program FilesApache Software Foundationapache-tomcat-7.0.64binreports.csv", and has in it a list of tomcat files(bootstrap.jar, catalina.bat, ...) and that's really strange because the generated file exists in the bin directory, but it's not this one who's downloaded...

Is the issue comes from the file path?

Comment: "file:///" + dir + "/reports.csv", needed the slash too, I have the good file now, but I still get the file name with the full file path "C-Program FilesApache Software Foundationapache-tomcat-7.0.64binreports.csv".

Comment: change `filename.getAbsolutePath()` with `filename.getName()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, the correct code is this:

```
URL url = new URL("file:///" + dir + "/reports.csv");
FileURLConnection urlConn = (FileURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String contentType = "text/csv";
ApplicationInstance.getActive().enqueueCommand(new DownloadCommand(
    new FileDownload(contentType,"inline", 
                     filename.toString(), 
                     urlConn.getInputStream())));
```

Comment: That is not the correct way to convert a file to a URL. Many characters (such as spaces) are not permitted in URLs.  The correct way to convert a file to URL is `filename.toURI().toURL()`, which will properly escape all reserved characters in order to create a compliant URL.